# is it possible to open findbugs xml report in some eclipse view

Tags: eclipse, gradle, findbugs

Our `gradle` build generates `findbugs.xml` so Jenkins Findbugs plugin can analyse it.

Is there any way to open nice readable form of findbugs.xml in `Eclipse` ?

Comment: This we already using... but this is not what i want :(

Answer (score 0):

You should install the FindBugs plugin for Eclipse. Let it run on every save and you will get way better (faster) feedback as by using the gradle result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Eclipse directly, but you can do it via the [FindBugs GUI](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/gui.html#d0e1167). You can basically create a run configuration in Eclipse to [call it up](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html), so it's *almost* as if you were using it from Eclipse.

Then, in the FindBugs GUI, choose File → Open and select the findbugs.xml:

[image: FindBugs GUI]

If the GUI does not show source code, you may have to configure where to find the sources. This configuration can be saved to a file, so that you don't have to do it every time you run it.